# Who is the other robot queuing in the HHGTTG movie?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

In the movie, there is a scene where the "heroes" are queuing to get Trillian released. There is a familiar looking robot in the background.

Who is this?

[image: Queuing]

[image: Robot head]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the original Marvin used in the [BBC TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(TV_series)). Here is is, from [BBC Online](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cult/hitchhikers/gallery/tv2/marvin.shtml):

[image: Original Marvin]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Marvin_(character)&oldid=683094778) also mentions that:

> A recreation of the [Marvin] costume from the 1981 television series makes an appearance in the film, as one of the robots standing in a queue on Vogsphere, where the main characters are trying to release Tricia.

See also [Geek Twins](http://www.thegeektwins.com/2012/02/old-marvin-meets-new-marvin-from.html) and [eeggs](http://www.eeggs.com/items/44703.html) (and another [eeggs](http://www.eeggs.com/items/54645.html) link).

Answer (score 8):

It's Marvin as he appeared in the 1981 BBC TV series

Comment: Welcome. Yes, you are correct. But please provide more info, ie back it up with evidence, preferably with links.